# C++ use operator delete for auto (stack) pointer

Tags: c++

Must I use operator `delete` for stack pointer?

For example:

```
User * p = new User;
delete p;              //needed?
```

Comment: Always `delete` what was allocated with `new`. The pointer is on the stack, but the object it points to isn't. `delete p;` will deleted the pointed object, not the pointer itself. You can avoid the question by using [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: You are not deleting the pointer. You are deleting the dynamic memory you've allocated. The fact that its address happens to be currently stored in an automatic pointer variable is irrelevant.

Comment: The `stack` tag is for the data structure `stack`. C++ as a language doesn't necessarily require a stack for storing objects with automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `delete` you are not deleting the pointer, so it makes no difference whether it is a stack pointer or any other kind of pointer.

When you use `delete` you are deleting the block of memory pointed by the pointer.  If that block was allocated with `new`, then it's always on the heap.  (If it was not allocated with `new`, then you should not `delete` it.)

Comment: While the general tone of the answer is correct, the example provided is very incorrect. By the same logic, `printf("%d", *p);` after `delete p` call is very much likely to print the same unchanged value (given p is `int*`), so does it mean `delete p` does nothing?

Comment: @SergeyA I removed the example from my answer, to make you happy.

Answer (score 2):

The other angle is that no, you **must not** use operator `delete`, because you should never use naked pointers in non-library code.

In modern C++, your example should be:

```
std::unique_ptr<User> p = std::make_unique<User>();
```

No `delete` and no `new` in sight.

**Note**: in this particulate case, `make_unique` could be substituted for `new` painlessly, but since in other examples it might not be, it's a good practice to teach yourself - `make_unique` is a function to use.